# calculating dynamic offset

Tags: programming

there are two given functions. One (blue) is detailed but has a certain offset from its actual value. The other (red) doesn't have this offset, but it is less detailed. I'd like to use the first function for further calculations, but without the offset. I can't just subtract a fixed value because the offset depends on various factors that are unknown (dy_1 ≠ dy_2). Is there any tool in math that can help me out?

[manipulating functions with dynamic offset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GZhAe.png)

These functions originate from two pressure sensors . Blue is input and red is output. You may ask, 'Why don't you fix the input sensor first?' I agree on that, but that's not how things are done here, apparently.

Also, is there a tool to draw functions other than paint?